# Macro with zero arguments - with or without parentheses

Tags: c-preprocessor

When defining macro with zero arguments we can define it with parentheses, thus looking more like function or without parentheses.

What is preferable (probably there's no right answer) way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, I would expect `MACRO()` to generate executable code, which may have side-effects. I use `MACRO` (sans parentheses) for more structural things that yield declarations, boilerplate, or constants.

Comment: ... or (perhaps the most common use) a constant.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to create a macro that mimics a function, then use the `()` version. Otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, we can](http://codepad.org/C2XvgtKD) and I don't think that there's really any particular technical reason why one is better than the other. However, conventionally we would omit the `()` where not required.

Comment: What are the cases () is required than? Is there any logical explanation to the convention?

Comment: Yet, another two answers are don't follow the convention, however it doesn't proof nothing.

Comment: `#define QUIT exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` or `#define QUIT() exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`? I prefer the 2nd even though the `()` are not required.

Comment: @dimba: How can you "prove" anything? There's no technical difference.